# Python: How to copy a multidimensional list by value without nested cycles?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, copy

I have a multidimensional list with lots of data and I need to copy it to another variable.

Both

```
b = a.copy()
```

and

```
b = a[:][:][:][:]
```

don't help - I still have data in `b` bound to data in `a`

Of course, I can copy it element by element with nested cycles (maybe only saving one level with `.copy()`). But is there a better way?

PS: The situation gets even worse if my data are in `dict` of `lists` or `dict` of `dict`s. So is there some compact way to copy such nested structures?

Comment: kindly read [ask]. Regards.

Comment: Try to look at [copy.deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from copy import deepcopy

b = deepcopy(a)
```